# How to deploy a Java 11 app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with CircleCI?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, circleci, java-11

I'm trying to deploy a Java 11 app to EB with Docker container via CircleCI.
How should the config files look like?

The build phase goes ok but the deployment phase stops to the point where the CircleCI won't find the Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json files.

I've tried to zip the jar and the docker files after `mvn package` but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

In .circleci/config.yml

```xml
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11.0.2-jdk
.
.
.
      - run:
          name: Build artifacts
          command: |
            mvn package
            zip Docker/myapp-0.1.0.zip target/myapp-0.1.0.jar Docker/Dockerfile Docker/Dockerrun.aws.json
.
.
.
  deploy-to-dev:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:11.0.2-jdk
.
.
.
      - run:
          name: Deploy to Dev
          command: |
            sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
            sudo easy_install pip
            sudo pip install awsebcli --upgrade            
            eb use myapp-env --profile circleci
            eb deploy -v --profile circleci
```

In .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

```xml
deploy:
  artifact: Docker/myapp-0.1.0.zip
```

Right now the CircleCI gives the following error

> 2019-10-21 07:27:00    INFO    Environment update is starting.
> 2019-10-21 07:27:04    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
>
> 2019-10-21 07:27:10    ERROR   Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json are both missing, abort deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I just needed to add `-j` to the zipping command.

```
zip -j Docker/myapp-0.1.0.zip target/myapp-0.1.0.jar Docker/Dockerfile Docker/Dockerrun.aws.json
```

Now the files are found and the app gets deployed.